# why i don't see all parts in html using django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I wrote the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if all_site %}
    <ul>
    <h3>Here all my site:</h3>
    {% for site in all_site  %}
        <li><a href="/site/{{ site.id }}/"> {{ site.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3> You don't have any Site.</h3>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

when, I run. I not see "Here all my site", but I only see the one contained in the for.

Comment: try moving `<h3>` outside of the `<ul>`, `<li>` is the only valid child of `<ul>`. most browsers should still render it though

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify it, for now a solution that I have found working is this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if all_site %}
    <h3>mmmmmm</h3>
    <ul>
    <h3>Here all my site:</h3>
    {% for site in all_site  %}
        <li><a href="/site/{{ site.id }}/"> {{ site.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3> You don't have any Site.</h3>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

in this case if I do run, i see:

```
here all my site:
  site 1
  site 2
```